# Powershell click button on website with dusk or title (no id or class)

Tags: powershell

I am trying to automate exporting csv file every week and trying to click 'Export Search Result' button on the SharePoint using PowerShell.
However, the button does not have id; it has dusk, title, type, and class.
The following is the html code for the button

[image]

I need a help how I need to correct my PowerShell script to make it work.

Comment: Wouldn’t PowerAutomate be better for this?

Comment: Something like `$exportCSVbtn = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('button') | Where-Object { $_.Title -eq 'Export Search Results' }` perhaps?